MutationObserver does not trigger when I use the network tab to throttle speed to slow 3G
Context: I want to delay loading of non-essential scripts until a dynamically created hero image has loaded.
"use strict";

import { siteNavHandler } from "./siteNavHandler.min.js";
import { buildHeroGallery } from "./buildHeroGallery2.min.js";
import { pageNavHandlerList } from "./pageNavList.min.js";
import { lazyLoadingCtaSection } from "./lazyLoadingCtaSection.min.js";

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
function init() {
  siteNavHandler();
  DelayScriptLoading();
  buildHeroGallery(); <----- This module loads the dynamic hero image
  pageNavHandlerList();
  lazyLoadingCtaSection();
}

function DelayScriptLoading() {
  const interval = setInterval(function () {
    if (document.querySelector("#heroImage0")) {
      console.log("Found! with polling");
      const img = document.querySelector("#heroImage0");
      img.addEventListener("onload", loadjs("polling event listener on load", img));
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 500);

  const target = document.getElementById("top");
  console.dir(target);

  function addHandler(records, observer) {
    for (const record of records) {
      for (const addedNode of record.addedNodes) {
        if (addedNode.id == "heroImage0") {
          console.log("MutationObserver triggered for " + `${addedNode.id}`);
          const img = addedNode.querySelector(".hero-gallery-img");
          img.addEventListener("onload", loadjs("MutationObserver event listener on load", img));
        }
        observer.disconnect();
      }
    }
  }

  const observerOptions = {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true,
  };

  const observer = new MutationObserver(addHandler);
  observer.observe(target, observerOptions);

  async function loadjs(param, img) {
    console.log("img has loaded and load JS function triggered using " + `${param}`);
    console.dir(img);
  }
}

However if I use chrome browser dev tools network throttling set to slow 3G the MutationObserver does not trigger but the polling interval does. When I set the throttling to fast 3G both the polling and Mutation observer trigger. What am I missing here that the Mutation observer does not work for slow 3G?
Console output with throttling set to slow 3G
controllerList.js:28 section#top.heroGalleryContainer
controllerList.js:20 Found! with polling
controllerList.js:52 img has loaded and load JS function triggered using polling event listener on load
controllerList.js:53 img#heroImage0.hero-gallery-img

console output with throttling set to fast 3G or higher
controllerList.js:28 section#top.heroGalleryContainer
controllerList.js:34 MutationObserver triggered for heroImage0
controllerList.js:52 img has loaded and load JS function triggered using MutationObserver event listener on load
controllerList.js:53 img.hero-gallery-img
controllerList.js:20 Found! with polling
controllerList.js:52 img has loaded and load JS function triggered using polling event listener on load
controllerList.js:53 div#heroImage0.hero-gallery-div.img--FadeIn

using script defer will not work because I want the scripts to load AFTER the dynamic hero image. Equally, async loading the scripts is not viable because I do not want them running in the background chewing up bandwidth UNTIL the hero image has loaded.

You probably meant to place the observer.disconnect(); inside the if block?

Tried that and the outcome is the same as before:
function addHandler(records, observer) {     for (const record of records) {       for (const addedNode of record.addedNodes) {         if (addedNode.id == "heroImage0") {           console.log("MutationObserver triggered for " +${addedNode.id});           const img = addedNode.querySelector(".hero-gallery-img");           img.addEventListener("onload", loadjs("MutationObserver event listener on load", img));           observer.disconnect(); <---------------------         }       }     }   } 

Does the observer never fire, or does it fire but with records that don't match your if (addedNode.id == "heroImage0") { so it's impossible to differentiate those two cases with your log statements as-is.

if (addedNode.id == "heroImage0") will always be "heroImage0". already tested that as can be seen from the console log outputs.

If you're 100% sure that's the case then fair enough but it definitely depends on implementation details that aren't provided in the question. The image could for instance be added as a child of another node, and then that node could be added to the DOM for instance, and then your code would not catch it. The MutationObserver API doesn't create records for nested child nodes of inserted nodes.

@loganfsmyth. thx you were right. in essance In the buildHeroGallery() module I have code that only loads one image if the network connection speed is less than 1mb (slow 3g). I was adding the ID "heroImage0" to the child not the parent of "addedNode.id". MutationObserver now works as expected.
